# How do I improve my composing skills

Tags: harmony, composition

I've been composing for over a year, since the pandemic has started. I've been composing a lot of simple pieces, most of them are SATB. I want to improve my composing skills because when I listen to some of my works they sound 'simple'.
How can I improve composing for SATB?
Can you include a pdf about four-part harmony please?

Comment: This question needs some revision, and possibly to be separated into separate questions. As written there are three issues: 1) It's a solicitation of opinions rather than a fact-based Q&A; 2) It requests a recommendation for resources, which is considered off-topic on this forum; and 3) It contains multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would now suggest you also start studying melody writing. Playing simple themes, such as melodies by classical period composers or folk songs would be a good place to start.

To get started look at the use of short scale passages, use of arpeggios,and interval leaps